# Ubuntu 17.10 halts while booting and an USB 3.0 HUB is connected

Tags: boot, usb

Just as the title says, whenever I boot my laptop, and my USB 3.0 HUB is connected ([Targus USB 3.0 4 Port Hub](https://www.targus.com/uk/usb-3_0-4-port-hub-ach119eu), the booting process will halt for about 30 seconds, after that the boot process will continue...

I'm pretty sure is the Kernel trying to wait for a response from the HUB (maybe an USB drive?), but I cant find any configuration to change this value...

Any help will be appreciated